# Error when creating vm with ssh key in azure

Tags: linux, powershell, azure

I'm getting following error when creating a VM in Azure:

```
$sshpub="ssh-rsa AAAAB3..."
New-AzureVMConfig -Name $VmName -InstanceSize $InstanceSize -Label $VmName -ImageName $Imagename -DiskLabel $DiskLabel  | 
Add-AzureProvisioningConfig -Linux -SSHPublicKeys  $sshpub | 
Add-AzureEndpoint -LocalPort $LocalPort1 -Name $LocalPortName1 -Protocol tcp -PublicPort $LocalPort1  | 
New-AzureVM -ServiceName $CloudServiceName -AffinityGroup $AffinityGroup –WaitForBoot
```

Error :

> Add-AzureProvisioningConfig : Cannot bind parameter 'SSHPublicKeys'. Cannot convert the "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1y....
>   "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.Model.LinuxProvisioningConfigurationSet+SSHPublicKey".

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is choking because you have a typo:
" - SSHPublicKeys  -SSHPublicKeys" appears in the middle of the Add-AzureProvisioningConfig call. It should be just "-SSHPublicKeys". This doesn't mean I understand how to really work with the command as you specify. See [**my question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33506926/azure-add-azureprovisioningconfig-ssh-key-or-key-pair-upload) to see how clueless I am.

Comment: yes, it's my typing mistake but in my powershell script write single time but and get above error; shell it   $sshpub direct working?