# Azure Add-AzureProvisioningConfig ssh key or key pair upload

Tags: linux, powershell, azure, ssh

Using Azure Powershell commandlets, I want to provision a new Linux VM with no SSH password and only SSH keys (necessary when provisioning CoreOS). When using the Azure CLI along with a public key file specified on the command line, everything works well. Apparently this is not available for the Powershell commandlet Add-AzureProvisioningConfig. It takes two possible SSH Key arguments, but they are both lists of key pairs. As [documented here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn495299.aspx), the argument -SSHKeyPairs  specifies a list of SSH key pairs already deployed in the subscription. I have no idea how to deploy key pairs in the subscription, nor can I find it documented anywhere. Likewise, -SSHPublicKeys  specifies a list of SSH public keys already deployed in the subscription.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Openssl.exe utility to generate the certificate.

Here is an example of what this command :

```
openssl.exe req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout myPrivateKey.key -out myCert.pem
```

Complete example of how to provision a Linux virtual machine using an SSH:

```
$location = "West US"
$serviceName = "contosolinux1"
$vmName = "linuxvm1"
$size = "Small"
$adminUser = "[admin user name]"
$password = "[admin password]"
$imageFamily = "Ubuntu Server 14.10 DAILY"
$imageName = Get-AzureVMImage |
where { $_.ImageFamily -eq $imageFamily } |
sort PublishedDate -Descending |
select -ExpandProperty ImageName -First 1
$certPath = "$PSScriptRoot\MyCert.pem"
New-AzureService -ServiceName $serviceName `
-Location $location
$cert = Get-PfxCertificate -FilePath $certPath
Add-AzureCertificate -CertToDeploy $certPath `
-ServiceName $serviceName
$sshKey = New-AzureSSHKey -PublicKey -Fingerprint $cert.Thumbprint `
-Path "/home/$linuxUser/.ssh/authorized_keys"
New-AzureVMConfig -Name $vmName `
-InstanceSize $size `
-ImageName $imageName |
Add-AzureProvisioningConfig -Linux `
-AdminUsername $adminUser `
-Password $password `
-SSHPublicKeys $sshKey |
New-AzureVM -ServiceName $serviceName
```

Source : https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/store/exam-ref-70-533-implementing-microsoft-azure-infrastructure-9780735697065

Comment: Didn't get a chance to try this without the account password. That is what I want (needed for CoreOS).